# Android: programmatically changing to a solid xml shape makes text disappear

Tags: android, xml

I have a Button in my layout whose background and textcolor are defined as selectors. When unpressed the button has a background color and a textcolor and when pressed another color and another text color - e.g. white background with black text -> black background with white text.

At a certain point in my code I need to replace the background/text color with a third set of colors and then go back to the original selector defined in the xml. However, after going back the text no longer appears and instead I get just a solid colored button.

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/somebutton"
android:layout_width="80"
android:layout_height="80"
android:textColor="@color/sometext_selector"
android:background="@drawable/somebackground_selector"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/sometext"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            />
```

At this point everything is fine, but when I do this:

```
someButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.backgroundRed, null));

someButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_light));
```

and then afterwards this:

```
someButton.setBackgroundDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.originalBackgroundSelectorDefinedInXml, null));

someButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.originalTextSelectorDefinedInXml));
```

is when the problems begin.

Here are the xmls for my selectors - apologies for pseudocode, just imagine appropriate hex values:

First - the background:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/color_purple_full" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/color_purple_full" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/color_purple_full" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/color_purple_outline"/>
```

color_purple_outline:

```
android:shape="oval">
<stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#somepurplehexa" />
<size android:width="80dp" android:height="80dp"/> </shape>
```

color_purple_full:

```
android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="#somepurplehexa"/>
<size android:width="80dp" android:height="80dp" /> </shape>
```

for text:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:color="@android:color/black" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:color="@android:color/black" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:color="@android:color/black" android:state_focused="true"/>
<item android:color="@color/green"/>
```

What I'm seeing is the correct background in the unpressed state but in the pressed state I'm just getting a solid color with no text on it at all. I'd be grateful for any ideas as to why this is happening and why in the original xml it works fine but only stops working after changing it programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

turns out the problem was here:

```
someButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.originalTextSelectorDefinedInXml));
```

should have been

```
someButton.setTextColor(getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.originalTextSelectorDefinedInXml));
```